# What is this little white creature?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Please identify this little and soft white creature. Since childhood I am seeing this things flying in my surroundings and nowadays they are seen occasionally.

[image]

Comment: it's a seed - similar to dandelion, many species use wind dispersal

Comment: It's indeed a seed. It could help if you mentioned the geographical origin of the seed, but it could help even more if you could trace it back to its source plant.

Comment: @DvPr could you tell your seed-like structure at centre of white circle on photo; whether was 1. narrow long (as looking in the photo), or 2. flat, (photographed at edge, so looking narrow rod-like)? Also, could you tell country or climate, and few more detailed photographs?

Comment: Okay I'm converting these comments into an answer. I wrote them as comment when I was new; so I wasn't used-to with the SE structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, as stated by @rg255 a seed (or actually a fruit, see below). The seed itself is the small brownish thing. The white hairs are attached to make the seed fly with the wind. Looking at the seed and the hairs, I think the seed belongs to the **daisy and dandelion familie asteracae/compositae**. Altough there are other possibilities, see comments.

EDIT: 
@AlwaysConfused is right if he states that in case of daisy family, it should be called a fruit, that containes one single seed. To be more precise, it is an Achene/Cypsula. In many species, what is often referred to as the "seed" is actually a fruit containing the seed. The seed-like appearance is owed to the hardening of the wall of the seed-vessel, which encloses the solitary seed so closely as to seem like an outer coat. Info derived from here on [fruits and seeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit#Simple_fruit) and more specifically on Achenes/Cypsela [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achene)

Comment: Thanks for this update; I'm converting the comments to answer. I wrote these comments when I was very new to SE so I was then not accustomed with the details of SE structure. Later I came to know that answers in form of comment is troublesome and considered as bad.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly a fruit or seed, having wind-dispersal mechanism.

But it could be

- 1. **a seed, having one-bunch of "*coma*"** (bundle of hairs on a small spot on a seed). Seed with coma is common in members of family [asclepiadaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepiadoideae) and [apocynaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocynaceae).

---

[*Asclepias syriaca*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepias_syriaca)

[image: Asclepias syriaca]

([Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepias)) ([Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Milkweed-in-seed2.jpg))

---

[Daemia extensa (Synonymous to Pergularia daemia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pergularia_daemia)

[image: *Daemia extensa*]

( [Text and Photo source](https://tekfor.blogspot.in/2010/09/blown-by-wind-seeds.html) )

---

[*Calotropis procera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calotropis_procera)

[image]

[Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Seed_Calotropis_procera.jpg)

---

---

Or may be a

- 2. **Fruit of [Compositae (Asteraceae)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteraceae)  with [Pappus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_(flower_structure)).**

Pappus looks same as coma; but from viewpoint of development it is different from coma. Most of the asteraceae member's fruits (these grain like structures are not seeds but fruits ('Cypsela', as user @RHA mentioned), containing 1 seed), contains persistent [calyx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepal); which is known as pappus, and commonly adapted for dispersal with air.

[image: Tridax flower]

A flower of *Tridax procumbens* showing epigynous calyx, which will later be persisted with fruit (from inferior-ovary) as pappus. [Image Source](http://seedplants.edowner.net/slides/Tridax%20procumbens%20disk%20flower.html)

---

Pappus of [*Vernonia cinerea* (Synonymous with *Cyanthillium cinereum*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanthillium_cinereum)

[image: *Cyanthillium cinereum*]

([Source](http://cnas-re.uog.edu/guam-weeds/cyanthillium-cinereus/)) ,  ([image](http://cnas-re.uog.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/vernonia-seed.jpg))

---

Pappus of [*Tridax procumbens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridax_procumbens)

[image: Tridax Pappus]

([Source](http://idtools.org/id/fnw/factsheet.php?name=14726)) , ([image](http://idtools.org/uploads/idtools/30/208/Tridax_procumbens_10_fl.jpg))

---

[*Taraxacum* sp.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taraxacum) (Dandelion)

[image: Taraxacum head]

[wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TaraxacumOfficinaleSeed.JPG)

This is a *Taraxacum* inflorescence (matured), showing fruits with pappus, attached with the receptacle, and a single fruit is like this:

[image: Taraxacum fruit]

([Source](http://www.seed-dispersal.info/further-information/dispersal-traits/diaspore-fruit-traits/diaspore-typology.html)) , ([image](http://www.seed-dispersal.info/uploads/RTEmagicP_Taraxacum_officinale_with_pappus_01.png)).

---

Source:

> 1. College Botany, Vol. 1 by Gangulee, Das and Datta; New Central Book Agency.
> 2. BOTANY for Degree Students / A. C. Dutta / Oxford